Using IIS MaxQueueItemAge performance counter
I want to use the built in performance counter MaxQueueItemAge from the "HTTP Service Request Queues" to measure how long the latest request to my application waited in the IIS queue.
This is how I initialize it:
var maxQueueAgeCounter = new PerformanceCounter(@"HTTP Service Request Queues", "MaxQueueItemAge", "<my app pool name>", true);

And I retrieve the measure like this:
var value = maxQueueAgeCounter.NextValue();

But this always returns 0.
I also tried getting the RawValue:
var raw = maxQueueAgeCounter.NextSample().RawValue;

but that returns some number that seems arbitrary, and remains fixed in every sample (even when requests flow in and out of the queue).
I know this metric works because when I use windows' perfmon tool the counter shows the actual values:

I tested other counters from my code and they work well, for instance this returns the correct number of requests in the queue:
var queueSizeCounter = new PerformanceCounter(@"HTTP Service Request Queues", "CurrentQueueSize", "<my app pool name>", true);
var value = queueSizeCounter .NextValue(); 


Do you want to get information about the latest request or the oldest request? For the latest request, you may need to use the NextValue() method twice. Simple refer to this: https://i.sstatic.net/KPEJ7JZG.png

The counter name suggests it returns the age of the oldest request, but at this point I'll be happy to get any value and work from there.
I tried calling NextValue() twice, with and without a delay between the calls.
I think that permon might be doing some calculation based on the RawValue, but I can't figure out what kind.

Unfortunately, I cannot find specific documentation on how to get these properties. Can you view this property in peformance monitor tool?

Yeah I couldn't find any specifics on this counter either.
In performance monitor tool I see it well - see the screenshot I attached above. The green line is the max wait time value.
